# Delphi Android XE7 Loading Bitmap Failed

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I developed a application . Its working very nice at my phone but its not working when this application start to workin at the other phones
Its closed after the showing splash screen.
I taking this problem ,'EBitmapLoadinFailed' 'Loading Bitmap Failed' when i debug at the phone of the using with the other phones.
 I have a bitmap in to listbox in my mainform.
 I disabled bitmaps in listbox its woking
my form create code is,

```
    procedure Tfrm_login.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
      strdb : String;
begin
 try
 strDB :=System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'user.s3db';
 with con do
  begin
    LoginPrompt                   := False;
    Params.Clear;
    Params.Values['Database']     := strDB;
    Params.Values['DriverID']     := 'SQLite';
    Params.Values['CharacterSet'] := 'utf8';
    Connected                     := True;
  end;
     sqlexe('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS AYARLAMA('+
            'ID    INTEGER     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,'+
            'TIP   NVARCHAR(50)    NULL,'+
            'DEGER NVARCHAR(255)   NULL)');
 except
   //fdf
 end;

end;
```

My Form Show Code,

```
procedure Tfrm_login.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
try
with myq do
 begin
  sql.Clear;
  sql.Add('SELECT * FROM AYARLAMA WHERE TIP='+''''+'MAIL'+'''');
  Open;
  if RecordCount>0 then
   begin
    first;
    edit_ad.Text:=FieldByName('DEGER').AsString;
   end;
 end;
 except
 /// tyrt
 end;

end;
```

Comment: You need to debug this. The code you showed has no bitmaps. TPath.Combine is your friend FWIW.

Comment: Im sory for my English but what is FWIW ?

Comment: You can use websearch to answer that. Always worth remembering that option.

Comment: Thanks i cant understand "for what is worth "

Comment: In this context it indicates a comment off the side of your main issue. It won't help with the primary problem but it's a useful tip.

Comment: I found out where the problem is me i have a form and the form has a listbox and listboxs items has a icon (png type) there is the problem when the create this form and listbox

Comment: Do you use pure XE7 or XE7 update1? Or just say build number from Help -> About

Comment: Hi Sergey.Im use XE7 Update 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think installing Delphi's Android 5.0 update will help if the device is Android 5.0. I have solved my same problem that way.

The link is : 
http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30110